# Eslint compatible feature exporting in Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, aurelia, eslint

The following code for adding an Aurelia feature generates eslint error

```
    import {PLATFORM} from 'aurelia-pal';

export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.globalResources([
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./CheckboxInput'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./DateInput'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./TextInput'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./SelectInput'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./ButtonHtml'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./TextAreaInput')
  ]);
}
```

It causes this eslint error:

```
[eslint] Expected a function expression. (func-style)
function configure(aurelia: any): void
```

If you change it to:

```
import {PLATFORM} from 'aurelia-pal';

export let config = function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.globalResources([
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./CheckboxInput'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./DateInput'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./TextInput'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./SelectInput'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./ButtonHtml'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./TextAreaInput')
  ]);
};
```

It makes eslint happy but it doesn't work with Aurelia. The aurelia-bootstrapper doesn't seem to know what to make of it.

EDIT: Solved it

The variable has to match to function like this:

```
import {PLATFORM} from 'aurelia-pal';

export let configure = function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.globalResources([
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./Toolbar'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./ToolbarItemButton'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./ToolbarItemLink'),
    PLATFORM.moduleName('./ToolbarItemDropdown')
  ]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your eslint configuration https://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-style

Comment: So far the only settings that I've found that works are to turn func-style: [off] or set it to warn to allow it to build with webpack using the eslint-loader. I am using the aurelia eslint plugin if that helps.

Comment: I dunno, that's not an ESLint rule I ever use.